# Why can't I use Data.Function.(&) in the same expression as Control.Arrow.(>>>)?

Tags: haskell, operator-precedence, infix-operator, parsing-error

Why can't I use `Data.Function.(&)` in the same expression as `Control.Arrow.(>>>)`?

I'm learning Haskell after spending a lot of time in F#, and I find that right to left notation is making it tough to understand longer pipelines. (I know it's not idiomatic)

I'd read that `&` and `>>>` were the Haskell equivalent to F#'s `|>` and `>>`. However, this fails:

```
[someList] & take 5 >>> sum
```

with a "precedence error":

> ```
> Prelude Data.Function Control.Arrow> [1:10] & take 5 >>> sum
> <interactive>:4:1: error:
>     Precedence parsing error
>         cannot mix `&' [infixl 1] and `>>>' [infixr 1] in the same infix expression
> ```

while

```
sum . take 5 $ [someList]
```

obviously doesn't.

Comment: That's unfortunate. As a workaround, one could define a custom module importing both qualified, and exporting them with the same same but a different precedence. That would not be terribly convenient to use, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not  "precedence error", it's "precedence *parsing* error" (emphasis mine).

If we try it in GHCi, `> :i &` replies with `infixl 1 &`, while `> :i >>>` replies with `infixr 1 >>>`.

So one (`&`) parenthesizes on the left (`infixl`) and the other (`>>>`) on the right (`infixr`).

The one with the higher precedence would win, but these two have the same precedence (`1`). And that's what the error message is telling us (a bit ineptly):

```
    Precedence parsing error
        cannot mix `&' [infixl 1] and `>>>' [infixr 1] in the same infix expression
```

means, because they have the *same* precedence, the *parsing* of these left- and right- associating infix operators mixed together in this expression is ambiguous, and hence impossible.

So you end up having to use explicit parentheses for this expression to *parse* properly:

```
[someValue] & (take 5 >>> sum)
```

By the way, `[someValue]` is already a list. Because you use `sum` its one element's type must be in `Num` (`someValue :: Num a => a`, `[someValue] :: Num a => [a]`).

But if you rather already have `someList` with several numerical values in it (`someList :: Num a => [a]`), you just write

```
someList & (take 5 >>> sum)
```

because `[someList]` is a list with a single value in it, which happens to be a list of numbers (presumably). So with `[someList]` the expression wouldn't work anyway:

```
> [5] & (take 5 >>> sum)
5

> [[3,4,5]] & (take 5 >>> sum)

<interactive>:431:1:
    No instance for (Num [t0]) arising from a use of `it'
    In a stmt of an interactive GHCi command: print it
```

Another way to make it parse, with  explicit parentheses on the left, is

```
(someList &) $ take 5 >>> sum
```

So the parens are closer together and the whole expression is potentially more readable, if you have long chain of expressions connected with `>>>` on the right.

Answer (score 3):

`&` has the right precedence to be chained on its own:

```
[1..10] & take 5 & sum
```

You don't need `>>>` for anything here, and `&` and `>>>` weren't co-designed so their precedence doesn't really fit for this use case.

Comment: it's worth pointing out that both `&` and `>>>` have the same precedence - 1.

Comment: @Chase it _should_ be pointed out, since _that_ is the reason for the error.